# Jest testing, call actual implementation on first call, mock the rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

We are moving a repo from sinon stubs to jest, and I'm having trouble with this mock. What I want to do is call the actual implementation on the first call, then mock the rest of the calls. This function is recursive, so we want the first call to call the actual implementation, then mock the recursive calls.

In sinon, it was done like this

```js
const stub = sandbox.stub(instance, 'function');
stub
  .onFirstCall()
  .callsFake(stub.wrappedMethod)
  .callsFake((args) => args);
```

I would like to do something like this, but cannot find the actual implementation on the jest spy or mock instance. Is this simply not possible?

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'function');
spy
  .mockImplementationOnce(spy.mock.actual) // ???
  .mockImplementation((args) => args);
```

Comment: Could you provide some context - why should the first call go through?

Comment: The function is recursive, so we would like to test the call count of the recursive calls.

Comment: Why? Is its being recursive not an implementation detail? Does the caller care?

Comment: I suppose it may be a bad test, but my goal right now is to get things working on jest.

Comment: Is migration not an ideal time to get rid of bad tests, rather than spending time migrating them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why can't you do something similar to as follows?

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'function');
spy
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => originalInstanceFunction())
  .mockImplementation((args) => args);
```

Here is an example implementation - Note had to store a reference to the original instance function

```
const original = {
    func: (args) => { console.log(`original ${args}`)} 
};


describe('test', () => {
    it('should call original then mock', () => {
        const originalFunction = original.func;
        const spy = jest.spyOn(original, 'func');
        spy.mockImplementationOnce((args) => originalFunction(args))
            .mockImplementation((args) => console.log(`mock ${args}`));
        
        original.func('test-args');
        original.func('test-args');
        expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(2);
    });
});
```

**Outputs:**

```
  console.log
    original test-args

      at originalFunction (test.test.js:2:28)

  console.log
    mock test-args

      at Object.spy.mockImplementationOnce.mockImplementation.args (test.test.js:12:42)
```

Comment: Doesn't that first example *not work*, because `instance.function` is the *spy*? If so there's little point leaving it in, and you certainly shouldn't without that caveat.

Comment: have edited - was not meant as a working example, working example is the example implementation.

Answer (score 12):

To do this with a mocked library, use `jest.requireActual()`. Copying an example from [the guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/bypassing-module-mocks):

```
jest.mock('node-fetch');
const fetch = jest.requireActual('node-fetch');
```

This allows you to mock the `fetch` library in your code being tested, but use the real `fetch` function in your test itself.

Comment: How can I do this with a react component? I mean, if I want ModalConfirmation.mockImplementationOnce(() => ModalConfirmationReal) where ModalConfirmationReal is the requireActual module and ModalConfirmation is the mock module.

Comment: @Luis In that case I would pass the function itself as the mock implementation: `MockFn.mockImplementationOnce(RealFn)`